# Comaximality of ideals of sets

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $I$ be an ideal of $k[x_1,x_2,...,x_n]$ and  ideal of set $V(I)=\{p_1,p_2,...,p_N\}$. Also let $I_i=I\{p_i\}$.Then how to show that $\bigcap\limits _{j\neq i}  {I_j}$ and $I_i$ are comaximal ideals

Comment: Please include your attempts.

Comment: The last sentence is not really understandable. What does $\cap_i\neq jI_i$ mean?

Comment: I have tried to prove it using $I$ and $J$ are comaximal iff $V(I) \cap V(J)= \phi$, but i m not getting it how to prove it

Comment: Ah! $V(I+J)=V(I)\cap V(J)$, and use the Nullstellensatz.

Comment: Can you please give me details